# Dense subset and probability space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a probability space, which is also a metric space. If a property is true "almost everywhere", does it necessarily mean that there is a dense subset of $X$ on which it is true? Can we find such a subset explicitly?

Comment: What does "dense" mean in the context of probability spaces?

Comment: @Trevor: I edited my post, $X$ is a metric space too.

Comment: I see.  But do we require any relation between the probability measure (or the algebra of measurable sets) and the metric? If every open ball has positive measure, then the answer to the first question is yes.

Comment: Yes we may assume that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments we should assume that every open ball has positive measure.  Then if the property $P$ holds almost everywhere, the set of points $A$ where it holds must intersect every open ball, so it is dense. This set $A = \{x \in X:P(x)\}$ itself meets the criteria that (1) it is dense and (2) property $P$ holds on it, and you can write it explicitly in terms of the property $P$, so I'm not sure what the last question is asking.